# Bluebird Warning : a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, async.js

I have an array of filenames which I iterate using this async module for node.

```
       async.eachSeries(imageStore, function(imageDetails,callback){
            mongoMan.updateCollection('imageStore',imageDetails,{_id: imageDetails.fileName}).then(function(res){
                  return callback(null, res);
                }).catch(function(err){
                  logger.error(err);
                  return callback(err);
                });
            },function(err){
              callback(null);
            });
```

The updateCollection() function is like this:

```
exports.updateCollection = function(collection, values, condArr){

  var result = imageStores.updateAsync(condArr, values, { upsert: true }).then(function(res){
    return new Promise.resolve(res);
  }).catch(function(err){
    logger.error(err);
  });

  return new Promise.resolve(result);
}
```

This code works well, updates DB and everything. But I am still unable to resolve the warning that bluebird throws:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
at Object.exports.updateCollection (/home/swateek/Documents/codebase/poc/apps/webapp/server/components/mongodb/mongoConn.js:46:22)
at /home/swateek/Documents/codebase/poc/apps/webapp/server/components/imageStore.js:72:24
at /home/swateek/Documents/codebase/poc/apps/webapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
at iterate (/home/swateek/Documents/codebase/poc/apps/webapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
```

Have looked up solution[here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it) but that ain't convincing enough in my case. Atleast is there a way to turn off the warning?

**UPDATE**

Please check the correct answer below, and here's how my calling function looks like:

```
function(callback){// post imageStore data to DB
          async.eachSeries(imageStore, function(imageDetails,callback){
            mongoMan.updateCollection('imageStore',imageDetails,{_id: imageDetails.fileName}).catch(function(err){
                  logger.error(err);
                  return callback(err);
                });
            return callback(null);
            },function(err){
              callback(null);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Do not use `async.js` with promises!

Comment: @Bergi will I run into problems with this? I am new to both, advice please?

Comment: Yes, you will, problems such as this. And also it will get a lot more complicated to handle errors, `return` promises in the appropriate places, and to chain promises easily if you are mixing them with node-style callbacks. Just don't. Bluebird has everything in its tool suite that you need. In your case, `Promise.each` or `Promise.mapSeries`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for trouble and throwing away programming advantages if you try to mix async library callbacks with promises.  Pick one structure or the other and use it everywhere.  Personally, I'd suggest you move to promises and just "promisify" functions that currently work with callbacks.  If you're using the Bluebird Promise library, then it has `Promise.promisify()` and `Promise.promisifyAll()` which make it pretty easy to promisify things that use the standard node.js async callback so you can just control everything with Promise logic.

Now, onto your specific issue.  That error means that you are creating promises within a `.then()` handler, but those promises are not returned or chained onto any previous promise.  Thus, they are completely independent from your other chain.  This is usually a bug (thus the reason for the warning).  The only time one might actually want to do that is you have some fire and forget operation that you don't want the outer promise to wait for and you aren't tracking errors on which is not what you have here.

Change to this:

```
exports.updateCollection = function(collection, values, condArr){
  return imageStores.updateAsync(condArr, values, { upsert: true}).catch(function(err){
    logger.error(err);
    // rethrow error so the caller will see the rejection
    throw err;
  });
}
```

Changes:

1. Return the main promise rather than creating a new promise.
2. No need for `return new Promise.resolve(res);` as `res` is already returned from that promise so you can remove that whole `.then()` handler as it isn't doing anything.
3. No need for `return new Promise.resolve(result);` as you can just return the earlier promise directly.

FYI, though you don't need it here at all, `Promise.resolve()` can be called directly without `new`.

Comment: Oh, a slight change did the trick. Removed the .then() part of calling function too.

Comment: @swateek - Then, the error is being triggered by something at a higher or lower level that you probably haven't shown us.  The revised `updateCollection()` code itself will not trigger that error.  There could be a problem in how `updateCollection()` is being called or in how the code works inside of `updateAsync()`.

Comment: please check the update I made, works now thanks so much! :)

Comment: A suggestion if you don't mind - is it a good idea to mix async with promises? Should I stick to one framework or mixing both is fine?

Comment: Uh oh.. problem now is when there are three rows to insert, it does only one. I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: @swateek - The first paragraph of my answer already says you should not mix async and promises.  Bad idea.  You are only making life difficult and making it easy to create bugs and making it hard to use the best features of either.

Comment: Thanks a lot, moved all to promises. Works pretty perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues here:

```
 var result = imageStores.updateAsync(condArr, values, { upsert: true }).then(function(res){
    return new Promise.resolve(res);
 }).catch(function(err){
    logger.error(err);
 });

 return new Promise.resolve(result);
```

Firstly: `Promise.resolve` is not a constructor so it shouldn't be used with `new`. Secondly: there is no point calling `Promise.resolve( result )` at all, just return `result` which is already a Promise. The intermediate `then` is pointless as well. You can reduce that code to:

```
return imageStores.updateAsync(condArr, values, { upsert: true })
  .catch( function(err){
      logger.error(err);
  } )
;
```

Comment: @jfriend00 You pretty much just repeated everything I said in my answer... Why not upvote it instead?

Comment: Yeah, apparently I misread some of what you said.  But your `.catch()` handler is wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well I wouldn't call it wrong. I'm just not making assumptions that the OP wants the caller to see the reject. He's the one that added the `catch` so I'm assuming logging that error is all he wants to do to handle it and the caller doesn't have anything to catch.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP does not want to return a rejection, but wants the rejection turned in a resolved promise with an `undefined` value?  There's a 99% chance that's a bug.